# Title: PHP script displays "Hello" then encounters "Connection refused" error on Docker setup with Apache and MySQL containers

Tags: mysql, docker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNPFI.png)I'm new to working with Docker, PHP, and MySQL, and I'm excited to learn and troubleshoot. I've been trying to set up a Docker environment with an Apache container and a MySQL container, and I've hit a roadblock with a "Connection refused" error in my PHP script.

I'm currently facing an issue with my Docker setup that involves two containers: one running Apache and the other running MySQL. Despite my best efforts, I'm stuck with an error that's preventing my PHP script from connecting to the MySQL container.

Here's the scenario:

- I have an Apache container and a MySQL container both running and operational.
  I can successfully ping the MySQL container from the Apache container.
  My PHP script (index.php) is supposed to connect to the MySQL container and perform some queries. *

However, when I run the PHP script, it only displays "Hello," and then I encounter the following error message:
`Hello Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Connection refused in /var/www/html/index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(12): mysqli->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 12` 
**Here's a snippet of my PHP script for reference:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$server = "172.17.0.3";
$root = "root";
$pass = "****";
$db = "mysql";

// Echo statements for debugging
echo "Hello"; // This gets displayed
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $root, $pass, $db);

// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
} else {
    echo "Connected"; // This is not reached due to the error
}

// Print host information
echo " Connect Successfully. Host info: " . $mysqli->host_info; // This is not reached due to the error
?>
```

Can someone with experience in Docker, PHP, and MySQL shed some light on what might be causing this issue? Any insights or suggestions for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your time and assistance!

I've reviewed my Docker setup, verified container connectivity, and made sure the credentials are correct. However, I'm unable to figure out why the connection is being refused.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wVW6.png)

Comment: Did you try to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as server ip? FYI: You should never connect as root to your MySQL database

Comment: The error means that either histname / port number uncorrect or mysql us not running or something actively blocks the connectuon. You need to figure out which of the above causes the error.

Comment: Your connection configuration is most likely not correct, please add your docker files to the question as well as the output of `docker ps`

Comment: even with 127.0.0.1 its still showing the same error